# What is the purpose of the “No DNA control”?

Tags: dna

What is the purpose of the “No DNA control”?

Recently I have done a forensic DNA lab experiment and I still cannot understand the use of “No DNA control”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No DNA controls (or water control, also "no sample control") are important to rule out false positives results due to contamination.

If your reagents/pipettes/equipment you use is clean, this reaction (I suppose in PCR) gives you no band. If you have a contamination, this will show up where no band should be and shows that you have a problem. In this case you cannot trust the other results as well.

Comment: Isn't it to know the protein level backgrounds in the given sample?

Comment: This is an instance of the general concept of a negative control -- a very important part of every experiment